# Is there a basic example of method of matched asymptotic expansions?

Tags: asymptotics, fluid-dynamics

I am studying a paper where the method of matched asymptotic expansions is used.  Unfortunately I have never seen this method before and am not sure how it works.

I don't really need the rigorous treatment as I only need the method for an application, so could someone just outline a very simple example which illustrates essentially how it works and what one is trying to do?

Comment: Check out this note: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m204/ch4.pdf

Comment: A bunch of related questions in the sidebar are appropriate, look in the perturbation theory tag.